# Why can't an annotation class infer type arguments?

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

Let's consider this code :

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class DeserializeInterface<T: Any>(val targetClass: KClass<T>)

interface A
class B : A

class Test {
    @DeserializeInterface<B>(B::class) val a: A = B()
}
```

at `line X` I write `@DeserializeInterface<B>(B::class)`, and Kotlin doesn't allow me to write just `@DeserializeInterface(B::class)`.

Why doesn't it infer type arguments in this case from `B::class`?

In contrast, type inference works here just fine:

```
class AClass<T: Any>(val a: List<T>)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = AClass(listOf(1,2,3))
}
```

but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a limitation in the current type inference algorithm. I have filed an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26637) you can follow.